# Find complete name (splitted into last name, given name) if it is in a list

Tags: python, string, list, methods, find

Here is my code:

```
def name_finder(studentList, names):
    studentList = studentList.split() #solves Tricky part
    names = names.split()
    for eachName in names:
        if eachName in studentList:
            return (True)
        else:
            return (False)


studentList = "Joshua Diaddigo, Marguerite Murrell, Jackie Elliott"
print(name_finder(studentList, "Jackie Elliott")) #True
print(name_finder(studentList, "Dave Elliott")) #True but return False because condition results in False because of "Dave" is not in studentList but Elliott is so this should return True. How do I get it to do such?
print(name_finder(studentList, "David Joyner")) #False
print(name_finder(studentList, "Jack Smith")) #False
```

I splitted the 'studentList'so it iterates each name (whether it is the last or given name). For example: it turns the list to "'Joshua', 'Diaddigo'".
I splitted the 'names' too so it does the same and not search as a complete name and instead search as its last name or given name.

I get stuck where it outputs "TRUE" when it sees "Jack" as a match to the first four letters in "Jackie".

How do I avoid this?
Is there a better way to structure my code?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you familiar with object oriented programming?
You can create an object called student with fields FirstName and LastName then set the comparer method to look at split strings and see if the first part matches First Name and the second part matches LastName.

Comment: @JuanAvalos Yes I studied Java before. I'm trying to use what I've learned so far in edX with my Python tutorial. Thank you for answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an object called `student` with a comparer and a string representation.
you can create any number of `student` instances initialized with strings and the objects can then be added to a list.

Once in a list, since it has `__eq__` defined, you can use `"First, Last" in StudentList` and it will return if the first or last name is in any of the student objects inside the list.

Here's the code:

```
class student:
    def __init__(self,first='', last=''):
        f=first.lower().capitalize()
        l=last.lower().capitalize()
        if ',' in first:
            spl = first.split(',')
            f=spl[0].lower().capitalize()
            l=spl[1].upper().capitalize()
        elif ' ' in first:
            spl = first.split(' ')
            f=spl[0].lower().capitalize()
            l=spl[1].upper().capitalize()
        self.FirstName = f
        self.LastName = l

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s, %s' % (self.FirstName, self.LastName)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, basestring):
            if ',' in other: ot = other.split(',');
            elif ' ' in other: ot = other.split(' ');
            else: return self.LastName.upper()==other.upper() or self.FirstName.upper()==other.upper()
        elif isinstance(other, student):
            return self.LastName.upper()==other.LastName.upper() and self.FirstName.upper()==other.FirstName.upper()
        return self.LastName.upper()==ot[1].upper() or self.FirstName.upper()==ot[0].upper()

students = [student("Joshua, Diaddigo"), student("Marguerite, Murrell"), student("Jackie Elliott")]

print 'jack smith' in students #Returns False
print 'jackie smith' in students #Returns True
print 'Joshua Murrell' in students #Returns True
print 'jack, SMITH' in students #Returns False
```

Note that the code accepts several scenarios, a `student` object can be initialized with first an last names separated by space or comma, the names are stored in Capitalized format and if `print student` is used, `First, Last` is returned.

The comparer also takes any combination of 2 strings separated by a comma or space and the strings can have any format. Hope this helps.

Comment: I appreciate this but I have not reached this with my tutorial in Python. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Read the code at the bottom first then come back here if you need clarification. The second line is a list comprehension. It splits the statement by comma not space so you end up with.

```
studentList = ["Joshua Diaddigo ", "Marguerite Murrell ", "Jackie Elliott""]
```

We do a list comprehension for x.strip() which takes each term and removes any spaces at the beginning and end of the names, and puts the names in a new list
    studentList = ['Joshua Diaddigo', 'Marguerite Murrell', 'Jackie Elliott']

The final line is a ternary operator style return statement.

```
return A if (condition is true) else return B
```

in this case

```
return True if (name in studentList) else False
```

## CODE STARTS HERE

```
def name_finder(studentList, name):
    studentList = [x.strip() for x in studentList.split(',')]
    return True if name in studentList else False


studentList = "Joshua Diaddigo, Marguerite Murrell, Jackie Elliott"
print(name_finder(studentList, "Jackie Elliott")) #True
print(name_finder(studentList, "Dave Elliott")) #True
print(name_finder(studentList, "David Joyner")) #False
print(name_finder(studentList, "Jack Smith")) #False
```

Comment: Dave Elliott still results in False! It should result in True. Any ideas?